# Is this a headlamp housing or a headlight bracket?

Tags: dodge, headlight, truck, ram

I have a **2015 Ram 1500 Crew Cab Sport 4WD**. Something on or near the driver side headlamp is broken:

[image]

The dealership is quoting me $600 to fix this broken piece of plastic, so I want to search aftermarket parts on my own. My problem is that I can't tell whether the broken part is a **headlamp housing** or a **headlight bracket**. If it's the bracket, here are 2 examples of the new part:

https://www.getallparts.com/2016/Ram/1500/Aftermarket-Driver-Side-Bumper-Cover-Reinforcement/p/CH2508108

https://www.autopartswarehouse.com/sku/Ram/1500/Replacement/Headlight_Bracket/2015/Sport/8_Cyl_5-dot-7L/REPD250515.html

And the answer is...?

Comment: For less than $600, you could be a decent 3D printer and make your own. That’s a ridiculous price.

Comment: I found it new on ebay for $130. I pray it fits and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you are looking for is the **headlight assembly**. I believe the tab which is broken on yours you can see sticking up in this image:

[image]

In my humble opinion, you are going to be better off finding an aftermarket set off of eBay or Amazon which will fit your truck. This way they match exactly. You could also try a pick-a-part or junk yard for your exact replacement, but seeing as how new the truck is, that may be a little bit hard.

Something to think about (which I don't see you mentioning) is *how did the tab get busted in the first place?* If it something obvious like a hit to the headlight, then it's a no brainer. If, you are not sure how it happened, you'll want to figure it out before you replace it. If you don't and just replace it, you might end up breaking the tab on the new one as well. This could be really important if there's an alignment issue with where everything goes together. Just a suggestion.

**Note:** If you are having trouble with your GoogleFu, here's a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=2015+Ram+1500+Crew+Cab+Sport+4WD+headlight&oq=2015+Ram+1500+Crew+Cab+Sport+4WD+headlight&aqs=chrome..69i57.2415j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which I used to find it along with an image.

Answer (score 2):

Headlamp housing is what you need.  I'm not familiar with that particular truck, but the bracket looks like something used for aiming/adjusting the position of the housing.  Typically, the housing will have direct bolts on some sides to hold it in place (what it looks like is broken), and other bolts will be adjustable somehow (which is what the bracket looks like).  That tab looks like it's a part of the black plastic of the headlight housing.

$600 sounds reasonable for replacing an OEM headlight housing because the part is pretty expensive from the dealer.  You can search for aftermarket headlights, but if you only replace one, it might not match exactly, and the non-OEM (cheap) headlights often don't fit as well and will require anything from hours of adjustment to physical modification to make them fit (read reviews if you are going to go aftermarket).

Comment: I agree! If you buy aftermarket parts you will fight them. One thing I have learned is aftermarket lighting assemblies usually do not fit well and after a few months you will see moisture behind the lens because they aren't sealed properly. If you want your truck to look and function like it did before the light broke... buy from the dealer and have the part  professionally installed.